# How to make overlay when image hover

Tags: html, css, overlay

So, I have gallery that contains some photos. I want to make when the image hovered then some information of the person is shows up, the name of person and the their role.

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

.flag {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.flag img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.biodata {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <div class="biodata"> HIS NAME<br/> HIS JOB </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used overlay to make the info shows up, but why the text is not in order and its not on the photo? I want its in the middle bottom on the photo. any suggestion? thanks before.

Comment: .biodata {height: 100%} not 0

Comment: It would help if you'd set up a fiddle. That way any1 who has time to help, has to invest less time to look into the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is updated snippet

```css
.gallery {
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

.flag {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  position:relative;
}

.flag img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

}

.biodata {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 0;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 10px) ;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  display:block;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  
}
.flag:hover .biodata{
  height:calc(100% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="flag">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300">
    <div class="biodata"> HIS NAME<br/> President of INASGOC </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the overlay is on the image, its still on the padding too. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zntksx0/)

CSS

```
.biodata {
      z-index:100;
    }
.flag:hover .biodata {
      height:100%
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
        .container {
          position: relative;
          width: 50%;
        }
        .image {
          display: block;
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
        }
        .overlay {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 100%;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          background-color: #008CBA;
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 100%;
          height:0;
          transition: .5s ease;

        }
        .container:hover .overlay {
          bottom: 0;
          height: 100%;

        }

        .text {

          white-space: nowrap; 
          color: white;
          font-size: 20px;
          position: absolute;
          overflow: hidden;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Shaki_Waterfall2.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">
        <p style="padding:20px;">I am Mr. Alven</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

​